# Http request not getting intercepted

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, interceptor

I have a interceptor class which extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter.
I have a endpoint in my controller which is annotated with
@RequestMapping(value="/abcd.action", method= RequestMethod.GET).

When I post a request in browser with localhost:8080/abcd.action. The call gets intercepted before executing the controller method.

But if I post a request like localhost:8080/.;/abcd.action the request going directly to controller class. Has anyone faced this issue before.

spring-webmvc:4.3.8.RELEASE

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import ims.aop.CustomActionsSecurity;
import ims.aop.NetworkAction;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper;

import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class HandlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping extends DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping {

    private Multimap<String, Registry> interceptedActions = HashMultimap.create();
    private UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
    private Pattern ignoreUrlPattern;


    @Override
    protected HandlerExecutionChain getHandlerExecutionChain(Object handler, HttpServletRequest request) {
        HandlerExecutionChain chain = super.getHandlerExecutionChain(handler, request);
        HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors = detectInterceptors(request);
        chain.addInterceptors(interceptors);
        return chain;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] determineUrlsForHandlerMethods(Class<?> handlerType) {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(handlerType, method -> {
            RequestMapping mapping = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            if (mapping != null) {
                registerIfAnnotationPresent(method, mapping, Interceptors.class);
                registerIfAnnotationPresent(method, mapping, RequestLogging.class);
                registerIfAnnotationPresent(method, mapping, CustomActionsSecurity.class);
                registerIfAnnotationPresent(method, mapping, NetworkAction.class);
            }
        });
        return super.determineUrlsForHandlerMethods(handlerType);
    }

    private <T extends Annotation> void registerIfAnnotationPresent(Method method, RequestMapping mapping, Class<T> annotation) {
        T methodAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(annotation);
        if (methodAnnotation != null) {
            String[] mappedPaths = mapping.value();
            for (String mappedPath : mappedPaths) {
                interceptedActions.put(mappedPath, new Registry(methodAnnotation, method));
            }
        }
    }

    private HandlerInterceptor[] detectInterceptors(HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<HandlerInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        String lookupPath = urlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(request);
        if (interceptedActions.containsKey(lookupPath)) {
            Collection<Registry> interceptorAnnotations = interceptedActions.get(lookupPath);
            for (Registry registry : interceptorAnnotations) {
                Annotation annot = registry.annotation;
                if (annot instanceof RequestLogging) {
                    RequestLogging loggingAnnot = (RequestLogging) annot;
                    interceptors.add(new RequestLoggingHandlerInterceptor(loggingAnnot));
                } else if (annot instanceof Interceptors) {
                    Interceptors intercAnnot = (Interceptors) annot;
                    Class<? extends HandlerInterceptor>[] handlerClasses = intercAnnot.value();
                    for (Class<? extends HandlerInterceptor> interceptorClass : handlerClasses) {
                        interceptors.add(BeanUtils.instantiateClass(interceptorClass));
                    }
                }  else if (annot instanceof NetworkAction) {
                    interceptors.add(new NetworkActionInterceptor((NetworkAction) annot));
                }
            }
        }
        return interceptors.toArray(new HandlerInterceptor[0]);
    }

    public void setIgnoreUrlPattern(String pattern) {
        if(pattern != null) {
            ignoreUrlPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        }
    }

    public String[] getFiltered(String as[]) {
        if (as == null) {
            return null;
        }
        List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : as) {
            if(ignoreUrlPattern == null || !ignoreUrlPattern.matcher(s).matches()){
                arraylist.add(s);
            }
        }
        return arraylist.toArray(new String[arraylist.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] determineUrlsForHandler(String s) {
        return getFiltered(super.determineUrlsForHandler(s));
    }

    private static class Registry {
        private final Annotation annotation;
        private final Method method;

        public Registry(Annotation annotation, Method method) {
            this.annotation = annotation;
            this.method = method;
        }
    }

}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="requestInterceptor" class="gb.app.security.overloadProtection.RequestHandlerInterceptor"/>
    <bean class="ims.aop.interceptors.HandlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="order" value="0"/>
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUrlPattern">
            <value>/api/*</value>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="requestInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you share your sample code and version information?

Comment: @iswailyildiz I have added the code and version info